# deriving formula for reflection over y=mx+b using dot product

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

So, I know that the formula for a generic point is 
$$\left(\frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2}x + \frac{2m}{1+m^2}(y-b), \left(\frac{2m}{1+m^2}\right)x - \left(\frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2}\right)(y-b)+b\right)$$ when you reflect it over the line $y=mx+b$. It's straightforward enough to derive that with complex mappings.

I need to derive the same result using the dot product and the projection of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'd really appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Comment: I took the liberty of TeXifying your original post.  I hope I did not mess up the coordinates for your generic point.

Answer (score 2):

Let's m <> Infinity (otherwise we have to use another line description).
P=(px, py) is point to reflect, P0=(x0, y0) is projection of P point to the line.
Vector PP0 is perpendicular to direction vector of the line (1, m), so scalar product of these vectors is zero:

```
(px-x0) * 1 + (py - (m*x0 + b)) * m = 0
```

Solve this equation against x0, then find `y0 = m * x0 + b` , then calculate reflection point

```
P' = P + 2 * (P0 - P) = 2 * P0 - P
```

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be a point of the line and $\vec u$ a unit vector along the line direction. If the line is given by its cartesian equation $y=mx+b$ you can take for instance $P=(0,b)$ and $\vec u={(1,m)\over\sqrt{1+m^2}}$.

Let $A$ be the point to reflect and define $\vec a=A-P$. The projection of $\vec a$ on the line is $(\vec u\cdot\vec a)\vec u$ so we get for reflected point $A'$:
$$
A'=A+2\big((\vec u\cdot\vec a)\vec u-\vec a\big).
$$
Substitute here $A$, $\vec a$ and $\vec u$ with their coordinates and you'll get your formula.